# Why OnValidatePrincipal is not called when navigating in Blazor pages and how to fix it

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-authorization

I have cookie authentication & OpenId setup to handle the `OnValidatePrincipal`:

```
.AddCookie(Constants.Cookies, options =>
{
  options.Events.OnValidatePrincipal = ValidatePrincipalAsync;
}
```

```
static async Task ValidateAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context) 
{
   //  context.Request.Path 
}
```

Inspecting the request path in the handler, I see it's is called for `Request.Path` with these paths: `/`, `/_blazor/initializers`, `/_blazor/negotiate`, `/_blazor`.

The handler is also called if navigate to any Razor server page (`Pages/Test.cshtml`).

But when I navigate in the Blazor app to different Blazor pages, the handler is not called.

Why isn't it called for Blazor pages too? Is it because Blazor server works with web sockets?

But isn't a problem that the validator is not called when navigating through the Blazor pages ? How to change so it's called for Blazor pages too?

Comment: "Is it because Blazor server works with web sockets?"  - Yes.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks. How to solve it? That's the real question

Comment: You may want to check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.navigationmanager.locationchanged?view=aspnetcore-6.0.